# How do i remove Responsive navigation bar from from single blog post

Tags: blog-page

How do i remove Responsive navigation bar from from single blog post.  Can you help me css code that take this out from my landing page. Can you please check the link http://interecom.co/event/silom-complex-craft-street/# .I am just looking to change my this blog post as I am using this one as landing page.

Comment: Here is the css code `#tg-nav {
    display: none;
}`

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help, I am still not able remove my responsive header with code. Can I try some thing else.

Comment: You don't need to. It should work. i tried to via developer inspector and it worked. you can add important key word as  ` #tg-nav { display: none !important; }` in case its not working. You can try adding style in `Appearance > Customize> Additional css`

Comment: Appearance> Customize > Additional CSS, then pasted code  still find no changes. I am sorry can you share screen short where it worked. Once again thanks for helping out

Comment: you can see here http://prntscr.com/j0mkbz  and http://prntscr.com/j0ml6m

Answer (score 0):

You will get different class name in body tag while on different pages.  You can use it and hide navigation.

In case of yours - use below CSS

```
    .single-ecwd_event #tg-nav{display:none;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. I tested this CSS with developer inspector, I am  still having same issue. Can i use some other CSS code. Thanks